# MediaPlayer : Possible to get camera informations from IPCAM streaming?

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer

I want to connect an IPCAM and display it with a videoView and a mediaplayer. Anyway I have an unknown error when trying to connect the camera. So I would like to know if there is indeed a connection to the camera. Is there a way, instead of mediaplayer return codes, to test the IPCAM connection and get some informations in return ?